# Unable to get optionsValue to work with dependent dropdowns and the Knockout mapping plugin

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am a database developer (*there's* the problem) tasked with emitting JSON to be used with Knockout.js to render sets of dependent list items. I have just started working with Knockout, so this is likely something obvious that I am missing.

Here is the markup:

```
<select data-bind="options:data,
                   optionsText:'leadTime',
                   value:leadTimes">
</select>

<!--ko with: leadTimes -->
    <select data-bind="options:colors,
                       optionsText:'name',
                       optionsValue:'key',
                       value:$root.colorsByLeadTime">
    </select>
<!--/ko-->
```

Here is the test data and code:

```
var data = [
    {
        key:"1",
        leadTime:"Standard",
        colors:[
            { key:"11", name:"Red" },
            { key:"12", name:"Orange" },
            { key:"13", name:"Yellow" }
        ]
    },
    {
        key:"2",
        leadTime:"Quick",
        colors:[
            { key:"21", name:"Black" },
            { key:"22", name:"White" }
        ]
    }
]

var dataViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

var mainViewModel = {
    data:dataViewModel,
    leadTimes:ko.observable(),
    colorsByLeadTime:ko.observable()
}

ko.applyBindings(mainViewModel);
```

As this stands, it correctly populates the `value` attribute of the second select list. However, if I add `optionsValue:'key'` to the first select list then the `value` attribute for that is set correctly but the second select list renders as an empty list.

All I need is for the `value` attribute of the `option` tag to be set to the `key` value provided in the data, regardless of where the select list is in the set of dependent lists. I've looked at many articles and the docs, but this particular scenario (which I would think is very common) is eluding me.

Here is a jsfiddle with the data, JS, and markup as given above: http://jsfiddle.net/tnagle/Lyxjt11y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To really see the issue, you can add the following code after the initialization of `mainViewModel`.

```
mainViewModel.leadTimes.subscribe(function(newValue) { 
  console.log(newValue);
  debugger; 
});
```

Before adding the `optionsValue:'key'`, line above will log the following output.

```
Object {key: function, leadTime: function, colors: function}
```

But after adding `optionsValue:'key'`, it log the following output.

```
"1"
```

or

```
"2"
```

The reason it failed was because when you assign `optionsValue: 'key'` to the first select list, `leadTimes` property of your mainViewModel which before will contain an object that has property color, now will be set to a string object. Then the select list just failed to find `color` property from `leadTimes` that has changed to a string object.

One of the way to make it work is by changing to this:

```js
var data = [
  {
    key:"1",
    leadTime:"Standard",
    colors:[
      { key:"11", name:"Red" },
      { key:"12", name:"Orange" },
      { key:"13", name:"Yellow" }
    ]
  },
  {
    key:"2",
    leadTime:"Quick",
    colors:[
      { key:"21", name:"Black" },
      { key:"22", name:"White" }
    ]
  }
]

var dataViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

var mainViewModel = new function (){
  var self = this;
  self.data = dataViewModel;
  self.leadTimes = ko.observable();
  self.selectedKey = ko.observable();
  self.selectedKey.subscribe(function(selectedKey){
 self.selectedData(ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.data(), function(item) {
        return item.key() == selectedKey;
    }));
  }, self); 
  self.colorsByLeadTime = ko.observable();
  self.selectedData = ko.observable();
}

ko.applyBindings(mainViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.3.5/knockout.mapping.js"></script>    

<select data-bind="options:data,
               optionsText:'leadTime',
               optionsValue:'key',
               value:selectedKey">
</select>   
  
<!--ko with: selectedData -->
<select data-bind="options:colors,
                   optionsText:'name',
                   optionsValue:'key',
                   value:$root.colorsByLeadTime">
</select>
<!--/ko-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but, and I'm sorry, I'm not following. Can you please elaborate on how to restructure this to correct the issue?

Comment: @ThomasNagle you can run the code snippet and inspect the element

Comment: I'm going to have to digest this to really understand it, but I see that it works! Thank you very much for the additional detail and debugging tip.

Comment: I made some adjustment to the answer, hope it helps :)